# Why does DataFrame.stat.approxQuantile fail with size of serialized results of n tasks (1030.8 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

`val postsQuantiles = posts.stat.approxQuantile("_score", Array(0.25, 0.75), 0.0)` is failing with the following error. I can obviously set `spark.driver.maxResultSize` to get past this error but I am curious why would this collect data to driver?

```
[Stage 3:==================>                                      (7 + 15) / 22]19/06/01 20:46:30 ERROR TaskSetManager: Total size of serialized results of 18 tasks (1030.8 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
19/06/01 20:46:30 ERROR TaskSetManager: Total size of serialized results of 19 tasks (1087.7 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
19/06/01 20:46:30 ERROR TaskSetManager: Total size of serialized results of 20 tasks (1145.6 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
19/06/01 20:46:30 ERROR TaskSetManager: Total size of serialized results of 21 tasks (1203.5 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
19/06/01 20:46:30 ERROR TaskSetManager: Total size of serialized results of 22 tasks (1261.4 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
[Stage 3:====================================>                    (14 + 8) / 22]org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 18 tasks (1030.8 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2131)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$fold$1.apply(RDD.scala:1092)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1086)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$.multipleApproxQuantiles(StatFunctions.scala:102)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions.approxQuantile(DataFrameStatFunctions.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions.approxQuantile(DataFrameStatFunctions.scala:75)
  ... 56 elided
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `approxQuantile` method follows the Greenwald-Khanna algorithm for computation of an approximate quantile (based from their documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions). It allows you to choose the relative error term.

In the documentation they warn you, that choosing the relative error `0.0` (as you have) can be very expensive, which is exactly what you are seeing. The algorithm is more suited for an approximate quantile than the direct quantile. The reason why so much data is being pulled, is because to compute the direct quantile it needs to pull all the data from the column into the driver at the very least.

You can read more about the algorithm from the published paper: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~datar/courses/cs361a/papers/quantiles.pdf

To overcome this I'd suggest to use the relative error term with some appropriate small value, which gives you the "*close enough*" confidence.

Comment: Are there other methods to calculate to quantiles without approximation in Spark?

Comment: You can use Spark SQL, that works. For example if you have a spark dataframe `df` and you wish to compute let's say median (50% quantile) of a column `foo`, you can do it like this `df.registerTempTable("df")` and `spark.sql("select percentile(foo, 0.5) from df")`